# Need different result in rounding off value in java

Tags: java, math

I am using following line of code to round off value in java

```
public class FloorTest 
{
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(Math.round(29.56));

        System.out.println(Math.round(27.62));

        System.out.println(Math.round(24.36));
    }

}
```

The output i got is **30, 28, 24.** But what i want is **29, 28, 24,** means only if value after point is greater than 5 round off to greater value otherwise not

Comment: `29.56`, value after point is greater than `0.5`, it's `0.56`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this method for you, but I really does not see the point of it :).

```
public static int roundWeirdly(double value){
    if (value - (int) value >= 0.6){
        return (int) value  + 1;
    } else {
        return (int) value;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks gud to me...but instead of doing cast inside, just use `Math.round` for < 0.5 and `Math.round()+1` ....why `cast` when u have pre-built methods??? +1

Comment: @NoobEditor - because in what I am doing, I am really casting it to int, I do not rounding it. Your way is using external libraries, it has more text and it is much slower. No reason to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative you can add 0.5 to your number and cast to int

Edit: will fail at your first example, output would also be 30

Comment: 27.62 + 0.5 = 28.12 makes 28 as an Integer. That would be correct rounding, 22.1 + 0.5 = 22.6 is 22 as an Int, also correct

Answer (score 0):

Now I you stated your requirement.

Then try this

```
Math.floor(number + 0.4);
```

Comment: this doesn't give the right answer, since he wants for 27.62 to return value 28

Comment: Updated the answer. Don't be so quick to minus.

Comment: But Math.floor(27.6) return 27, but my requirement is if the value after point is grater than 5 the round of to greater value eg: 22.6 to 23, 23.72 to 24. But if the value after point is less than 5 then do it like that eg 22.5 to 22, 22.57 to 22 22.4 to 22